# What properties of an item should be included in the json schema?

Tags: jsonschema, raml

I am confused about for which situation I am defining the properties in my json schemas.

Assume I have an item `product` for which I am trying to define a schema. In my database the `products` table has `id`, `brand_id`, `name`, `item_number` and `description`. All except `description` are required fields. The `id` is autogenerated by the database and the `brand_id` is set upon creation automatically by the api based on the user creating.

This means I can `POST /api/products` using only the following data:

```
{
  "product": {
    "name": "Product Name",
    "item_number": "item001"
  }
}
```

However, how should I now define the product schema? Should I include the properties `id` and `brand_id`? If so, should I label them as required, even though they are set automatically?

This is what I came up with:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net/products",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "item_number": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/products/item_number",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/products/name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/products/description",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "null"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "item_number",
    "name"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only define in your JSON schema properties that are dealt with by the user of the API.

In your case, it makes no sense to have `id` and `brand_id` in the schema that defines the POST body entity for the creation of a new `product` because these values are not provided by the API user.

This said, you may have another schema for existing `product` entities where these two fields are present, if it's OK to expose them publicly.

If that's the case, for this you can use schema union mechanism and have the "existing product" schema use `allOf` `new_product.json` and add `id` and `brand_id` to it.

Comment: Thank you David. For anyone who will find this with the same question as me I found a good write up for the union mechanism that David mentions at http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html well worth the read.